# what benefits quantum offer over classical parallelism

Tags: quantum-cryptography

What is the benefits of quantum computing vs parallel processing using classical computer ?

Can classical parallel processors outperform  quantum computing ?

Comment: Remainder: one 1970 [Intel 4004](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_4004) outperforms by orders of magnitude any available quantum computing device of a structure hoped/feared to become, in the future, usable for cryptanalysis (this excludes quantum-named computers specialized in [quantum annealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_annealing), which do not aim at running Grover's or Shor's algorithms).

Answer (score 1):

> **1.** What is the benefits of quantum computing vs parallel processing using classical computer?

The answer is in terms of Cryptography;

### Quantum Computing (QC)

- Key search on Block ciphers;  [Grover's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grover%27s_algorithm) is a brute-force quantum algorithm with complexity $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{N})$ with asymptotically optimal on unstructured data.
- Public key algorithms;

  - RSA factorization problem; [Shor's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/en/Shor%27s_algorithm) can efficiently factor integer $n$ in $\mathcal{O}((\log n)^2(\log \log n)(\log \log \log n)$
  - Discrete logarithm problem; [Shor's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/en/Shor%27s_algorithm) can efficiently solve.

Therefore, RSA, Diffie–Hellman, and Elliptic Curve Diffie–Hellman could be broken easily.

### Parallelization

- Parallel computing in keys searches only help linear time whereas using single QC already gives quadratic speed up. Examples are [Distributed.net](http://www.distributed.net/Main_Page), [DES Cracker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/en/EFF_DES_cracker), [COPACOBANA](http://www.copacobana.org/) [hashcat](https://hashcat.net/hashcat/)
- Parallel computing is used in factorization algorithms where the help again is linear with complexity;

  General Number Field Sieve with superpolynomial scaling: $$\mathcal{O}(exp [ c (\ln n)^{1/3} (\ln \ln n)^{2/3}])$$

> **2.** Can classical parallel processors outperform quantum computing?

Firstly, quantum give new complexity classes;

> The class of problems that can be efficiently solved by quantum computers is called **BQP**, for "bounded error, quantum, polynomial time".<sup>[7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_computing)</sup>
>
> BQP is suspected to be **disjoint from NP-complete** and a **strict superset of P**, but that is not known. Both integer factorization and discrete log are in BQP.

Some $NP$ problems can be solved efficiently.

A Turing machine can [simulate](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1/can-a-turing-machine-simulate-a-quantum-computer) a QC and QC can [simulate](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/23/can-a-quantum-computer-simulate-a-normal-computer?noredirect=1&lq=1) A Trung machine too,. So, once A QC is built, you can outperform a QC only by money.

### Cost<sup>[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/en/Shor%27s_algorithm)</sup>

An important subject is also the cost of running the algoriths.

Daniel J. Bernstein asked the question in ["Cost analysis of hash collisions: Will quantum computers make SHARCS[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grover%27s_algorithm) obsolete"](https://cr.yp.to/hash/collisioncost-20090823.pdf). Some results if a QC is built;

- Factorization; QC much more scalable and much more cost effective

  - The number-field sieve factors b-bit RSA moduli in time $2^{b^{1/3+\mathcal{o}(1)}}$
  - If a QC can be built for $b^{\mathcal{\Theta}(1)}$ Euros can factor b-bit integer in $b^{\mathcal{\Theta}(1)}$ seconds.
- Pre-Image Search;

  - Traditional hardware can find in $2^bh$ operations
  - Quantum; much more cost effective

    - Grover $2^{b/2}h$ operations on $\mathcal{\Theta}(h)$ qubits.
    - Shor’s speedup from $2^{b^{1/3+\mathcal{o}(1)}}$ to $b^{\mathcal{\Theta}(1)}$
  - Collision search; He claims that all quantum algorithms upto his paper are less cost-effective than the traditional.
  - Parallelization
  - A size-$M$ machine finds collisions in time roughly $2^b/M^{3/2}$. if size $2^{b/3}$ than collision time is $2^{b/2}$ with $\epsilon$ time with $\epsilon$ probability.
  - a size-M QC after $2^{b/2}h\epsilon$ quantum operations each unit has $\epsilon^2$ success probability. After $2^{b/2}h/M^{1/2}$ total quantum operations the size-M machine has $M\epsilon^2$ success probability. If the size a quantum computer is $2^{b/3}$ then the time for finding collisions is approximately $2^{b/3}$. Compare to classical.

and he added;

> Anyone afraid of quantum hash-collision algorithms already has much more 
>    to fear from non-quantum hash-collision algorithms.

---

<sub>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grover%27s_algorithm)</sub> Special-Purpose Hardware for Attacking Cryptographic
Systems

[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/en/Shor%27s_algorithm) Special Thanks to Ella-Rose for the article.

Comment: [Related paper by djb](https://cr.yp.to/hash/collisioncost-20090823.pdf) that discusses how the cost of some quantum attacks are not less than the cost of classical attacks